# expression not evaluating in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am using `ng-repeat` with a custom directive. The markup is

```
<div foo ng-repeat="item in [{url:'var',text:'one'},{url:'char',text:'two'}]">
 <img src="{{item.url}}" />
 <p>{{item.text}}</p>
</div>
```

The directive definition is

```
app.directive('foo',function(){
  return{
    restrict : 'A',
    transclude:'element',
    scope:{},
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl,transclude){
      transclude(function(clone,transScope){
        console.log(clone.html());
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Considering ng-repeat has a priority of 1000 and custom directives have a default priority of 0, the ng-repeat's compile and link will run before foo's link. This would mean ng-repeat would have added the new DOM elements in  and the foo's link should have access to these elements.

When i do a `console.log(clone.html())`, the console shows

```
<img src="{{img.image}}">
<p class="ng-binding">{{img.text}}</p>
```

Why are the expressions not evaluated when i get the clone of the DOM element even after ng-repeat is done with the compile and link phase.
What am i missing?

**EDIT**

Just realized that it is not specific to `ng-repeat`

The behavior is the same if we use the below markup

```
<div foo>
 <img src="{{item.url}}" />
 <p>{{item.text}}</p>
</div>
```

Considering `item` defined in the parent controller's scope, the expressions are still not evaluated when trying to get the DOM in transclude function. The directive definition remains the same as mentioned above.

The `console.log(clone.html())` line still shows

```
<img src="{{img.image}}">
<p class="ng-binding">{{img.text}}</p>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just read HTML in the next digest cycle, for example `$timeout(function() { console.log(element.html()) })`. You also don't need transclusion here.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks....worked for me.....could you please explain why is the expression evaluated in the next digest cycle?

Comment: This is because the changes make by  $digest/$apply/$watch would be in a asynchronous way. The callstack would be `$watch => $evalAsync => $browser.defer => setTimeout`.

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang would need a bit more explanation :(